# Unknown action The action 'create' could not be found for PostsController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end
  def new
  end
  def Create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    @post.save

    redirect_to @post, :notice=> "created"
  end

  private
  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body)
  end
end
```

Comment: i m new to rails and i m getting error :Unknown action   The action 'create' could not be found for PostsController

Comment: check your routes using `rake routes` in terminal and please make sure you have `resources :posts` in your routes.rb. secondly `create` should be lowercase too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have your methods lowercase. Change `Create` to `create`.